# The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I have an issue with an SSIS load. The table has loaded previously and it looks like nothing has changed so I'm surprised it doesn't load.

The error is:

> ERROR: Data Conversion Failed. The data conversion for column "XXXX"
>   returned status value 2  and status text "The value could not be
>   converted because of potential loss of data".

Also the error is on ROW 2.

A sample of the data is `0.177814688185796` or `-0.00246545402155979`. The current data type is  `NUMERIC(38,10)` and the max length of the column is 21 if I check in Excel. Tried changing to `NUMERIC(38,30)` but got same error.

If input manually using Import Wizard and suggested data type the data type outputted is REAL.

Was going to try change to float in SSIS but though I would see if anyone here had any suggestions.

`Retain NULL Values` is also switched on.

Comment: Those numbers seem to have a lot more than ten decimal places ... what if you used NUMERIC(38,20)?

Comment: Where are you editing the data types?  There are a number of places in a data flow task where the type can be persisted: are you modifying the destination table?  Did you check the Advanced Properties of your source/transformation/destination components to see if one of them is still using the old data type?

Comment: where is error happening? on 'data conversion' element?

Comment: The error is happening in OLE DB Destination. The external columns for OLE DB Destination are out of sychronisation with the the data source columns.

Comment: Looking back at last month's file the data in this column was the same type

Comment: We changed the data type to NUMERIC (38,30) in the Flat File Connection Manger and in the destination table

Comment: When you look at the file that caused the error, do you see any values for that column that are more than 21 characters?  NUMERIC(38,10) would allow a 38-character value to be passed to a 21-character column.  Can you expand the width of the excel column to 40+ characters?

Comment: 21 is the longest like this -0.000648145263265788

Comment: Colin, did you follow the suggestion I posted of right-clicking the destination component and confirming in the Advanced properties editor that the data types used by SSIS are correct?

Comment: What I did was go to Flat File Connection Manager, Advanced, configure the properties of the column. Changed it here from NUMERIC (38,10) to NUMERIC (38,30). Then I changed the desitination table in SQL Server to the same. Do you mean something more.

Comment: Since then I have changed the DataType to Float and it uploaded ok.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution, @colin.kane!  Go ahead and mark this as answered: a great way would be to write up a clear description of how you went about solving the problem (think about writing it to some guy in the future who has the same issue and no clue what to do next), post that as the answer to your question, and accept it by clicking the checkbox. This tells SO that your problem is fixed now, and tells future searchers that there might be an answer to be found here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this question I had an issue where data was not uploading as data type NUMERIC (38,10). I changed the data type to float and the data uploaded ok.